# Create a timed application

Tags: java, time, long-integer

I create a simple game that requires you to guess a number within a certain amount of turns (eg. 10). However, that makes the quite easy to beat. What I need help is how to keep track of how long the game has been going on for.

This is what I have thought up of so far (minus the game logic), but it doesn't seem to be working

```
Random ranNum = new Random();   
double input;   // The input
long startTime; // The time the game started
long curTime;   // The time the game ended

    double randNum = ranNum.nextInt(100);

while (curTime > 1000){
            curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            input = TextIO.getlnDouble();

            if (input = Math.abs(randNum)){
                System.out.println("You got the correct answer");

            }   // End if statement

            else {
                System.out.println("You did not have the correct answer");
                System.out.println("The number was" + randNum + ".");

            }   // End else statement

        } // End while statement
```

Comment: where you intializing curTime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the current timestamp before the loop begins:

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //get timestamp

//the condition is waaaay off, basically equals to while (true) - more on that later
while (curTime > 1000){
        input = TextIO.getlnDouble();

        if (input = Math.abs(randNum)){
            System.out.println("You got the correct answer");

        }   // End if statement

        else {
            System.out.println("You did not have the correct answer");
            System.out.println("The number was" + randNum + ".");

        }   // End else statement

    } // End while statement

curTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //get timestamp again

System.out.println("Game took " + ((curTime-startTime)/1000) + " seconds");
```

From the documentation of the [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class:

> **public static long currentTimeMillis()**
>
> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds.
>
> See the description of the class Date for a discussion of slight discrepancies that may arise between "computer time" and coordinated universal time (UTC).
>
> **Returns:**
>
> **the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.**

So to get the duration of the game, you have to take two timestamps, and usbtract the latter from the former...

Also, the while loops condition is way off... This

```
while (curTime > 1000){
```

is basically `true`... It would only be false on 1st of January, 1970, from 00:00:00 to 00:00:01

You could probably have something like this:

```
while(curTime-startTime > 10000) { //remember, value is ms!
   //...loop content
   curTime = System.currentTimeInMillis(); //update timestamp
}
```

But it would not make the game end exactly after 10 seconds. If you'd like to restrict how long the game can go on, that is a different kind of cookie - you'd have to have another thread to be able to accomplish that...

Answer (score 0):

are you not using startTime ?

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

currTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
```

Now the currTime will have the time difference in milliseconds.